# Omit display of HTTP requests by URL or other means

Tags: visual-studio, filter, fiddler

When using Fiddler for web debugging with Visual Studio, the vast majority of requests appear to be Visual Studio keepalive's which have nothing to do with development of the website.

I just discovered the "Filters" tab which includes: `Show only if URL contains:`, but I don't see anything like "Do not show if URL contains:"

Below is an image showing the traffic in question.

[image]

The contents of which resembles:

```
GET /67e56dbd9660475b992bdb4884bf024c/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAA9mo0FfMdkuV%2FOrook6XLgAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACdwdngu4Q3YaxNPSSSB6SaAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAEpHLB83IL2dS4l5v3LvZ4woAAAAPAHEqYMxK%2Fwwk%2Be%2FEq3MMrbOM4ao8Nhip4toaFxOxM0ARXitnQCueRQAAADELXsi%2FlcBeN%2BcFxQKtcMb7Yvd3A%3D%3D&messageId=d-B39A7C95-E4%2C0%7CE7%2C4%7CE8%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A56602%2FReticleDatabase%3Fsubmit%3DSearch%26process%3D%26device%3D%26lev_no%3D999%26xadj%3Dtrue%26xadj%3Dfalse%26xmag1%3Dtrue%26xmag1%3Dfalse&browserName=Internet+Explorer&tid=8&callback=jQuery18206701631324945791_1391540298842&_=1391540397878 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:56602/ReticleDatabase?submit=Search&process=&device=&lev_no=999&xadj=true&xadj=false&xmag1=true&xmag1=false
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:61010
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

How can I filter (not display) this junk data in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler offers *many* ways to filter data. The most powerful mechanism is FiddlerScript. Click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to `OnBeforeRequest` and add:

```
if (oSession.urlContains("SignalR/poll?")) { oSession["ui-hide"] = "FiddlerScript hides signalR"; }
```

Save the file.

(It's not entirely clear that SignalR's longPolling requests really have "nothing to do with development of the website", but if you don't want to see them, they're easily hidden.)

Incidentally, the next build of Fiddler's Filters tab will include a **Hide URLs containing** option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for implementing the new feature!
For future readers, by entering `arterySignalR` into the new "Hide if URL contains" field, I no longer see Visual Studio spam.